# Bad printed text within pages with colour elements (but ok with acroread)

Tags: 16.04, drivers, printing

I have some problems printing colour pages with a RICOH Aficio MP3501 network printer (I can't change printer), in the sense that the black text is .. how would be the name in English? "blurred" ?

See the left side of the following printed scans, and compare it with the right side:

[image: print comparition]

What could cause this problem (and how could I solve it) ? A few notes:

- I have this problem only when printing colour and only when the page
  itself contains - even minimally - some colour;
- CUPS test page and Abobe Acrobat Reader (acroread) prints fine, but all the other software in the     system (Libreoffice, evince, gnome pdf reader, firefox..) have this
  problem;
- I already tested all the possible settings of the printer
  (driver, colour saving mode, resolution..), ...no effects.

Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: and a photocopy in color works fine? if not, probably color printheads of your printer aren't working properly, need a little cleaning

Comment: No, photocopy works great, as well as for my colleagues in Windows. Also, as I said, in Linux, if the page is printed by acroread, it works great (right side).

Comment: sorry, "acroread" isn't a word that I know, even google don't translate it

Answer (score 0):

I solved changing back to the default driver and setting the options in this way.. no idea which particular option is the one that really did the difference, as I did already tried many times before.. so the only things I know is that this set of options now works :-) :

Printer works with:

- Driver: default (I did change driver to generic and then change it back again to the recommended one)
- Resolution: 600dpi
- Gradation: standard
- Dithering: text
- Color mode: color
- Gray reproduction (Text/Line Art): Black/Gray by K
- Black over print: off
- CMYK Simulation profile: off
- Printer profile: no profile available
- Image smoothing: off
- Color setting: off
- Color profile: auto
- Barrier-free color management: off
- Separate into CMYK: do not separate